# magit-status doesn't use the whole screen size in 2.3

Tags: magit

In previous versions (before 2.3) `M-x magit-status` showed the status buffer taking the whole size of the current window.  However, now it instead pops up a half-sized buffer (like e.g. `C-h f` does).  This looked fine but only until I wanted to review a diff of changes, as then it became apparent I want a full-sized window with the status buffer.

Is it possible to return the previous behavior of `M-x magit-status`?

Comment: The 2.3 release notes discuss this change a bit, see https://raw.githubusercontent.com/magit/magit/master/Documentation/RelNotes/2.3.0.txt. "All Magit-Mode buffers ... are now displayed using `magit-display-buffer`, which is a wrapper around the low-level `display-buffer` ... " There is some additional discussion about how to customize buffer display behavior via the `magit-display-buffer-function` option, but I haven't experimented with this yet.

Answer (score 5):

Magit itself did never make the status buffer full screen.  But many
starter-kits do that and there also exist a few blog posts which
explain how to do it.  You are probably using such a starter-kit or a
snippet you found somewhere, and that code stopped working due to
changes in Magit v2.3.

These changes are actually intended to make it easier to customize how
Magit buffers are displayed and switched to, but apparently these
changes also break some existing kludges which were previously used to
accomplish the same without any explicit support in Magit.

Starting with v2.3 Magit displays all Magit (-mode derived) buffers
using `magit-display-buffer` which in turn calls the function
specified by the option `magit-display-buffer-function`.  The default
value is `magit-display-buffer-traditional` which displays the buffer
in much the same way as in previous releases.  All the rules which
control how certain Magit buffers are displayed are now contained in
this function, previously they were scattered all over the place.

You can learn more about this in
[Switching Buffers](http://magit.vc/manual/magit/Switching-Buffers.html)
from the Magit manual and in
[Choosing a Window for Display](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Choosing-Window.html)
from the Elisp manual.

Once you have found a satisfactory solution to make the status buffer
full screen (which uses "display actions" instead of third party
packages), then please post that here.

Comment: FWIW, the solution I posted is still working. But thanks for this comment, I'll try reworking that "fix" with solution closer to Magit standards.

Comment: Well, in the post itself I said "as large as the current window", which is what I really meant, title is a misnomer. To return the old behavior I now customize `magit-display-buffer-function` to `(lambda (buffer) (switch-to-buffer buffer) (selected-window))`.

Comment: Which is not that good, because it also makes diff buffer when committing take the whole window... In general, new options are nice, except it would be even nicer if you provided a simple way to retain old behavior.

Comment: I did. `magit-display-buffer-traditional` is supposed to display the buffer as it would traditionally have been displayed, and I think it mostly succeeds in that. What broke is a third-party hack and I now provide a way to implement that without using a hack. Implementing that is quite simple, though not as trivial as the snippet you posted.

Comment: You could improve you snippet by adding `(if (derived-mode-p 'magit-status-mode) ...`.

Comment: That's what I did to get only `magit-status` fullscreen and it is working. (see my answer)

Comment: Yeah, but you deleted that answer and so @doublep doesn't see it because s/he doesn't have enough karma. Nevermind, you added it to your other answer.

Comment: Yes, but I updated my first answer adding the solution at end of it.

Comment: Yes, but I updated my comment adding a note about me having noticed that at end of it. :-)

Answer (score 4):

This is what I was doing before Magit 2.3, adapted from [What the .emacs.d!?](http://whattheemacsd.com/setup-magit.el-01.html):

```el
(defadvice magit-status (around magit-fullscreen activate)
  "Turn fullscreen on for magit-status."
  (window-configuration-to-register :magit-fullscreen)
  ad-do-it
  (delete-other-windows))

(defun magit-quit-session ()
  "Restore previous window configuration and cleanup buffers."
  (interactive)
  (mu-kill-buffers "^\\*magit")
  (jump-to-register :magit-fullscreen))

(bind-key "q" #'magit-quit-session magit-status-mode-map)

(defun mu-kill-buffers (regexp)
  "Kill buffers matching REGEXP without asking for confirmation."
  (interactive "sKill buffers matching this regular expression: ")
  (cl-letf (((symbol-function 'kill-buffer-ask)
             (lambda (buffer) (kill-buffer buffer))))
    (kill-matching-buffers regexp)))
```

The difference from the solution on What the .emacs.d!? is that I like `q` to close all Magit buffers and not only `magit-status`.

If you don't have `bind-key`, you can just use regular `define-key`:

```el
(define-key magit-status-mode-map (kbd "q") #'magit-quit-session)
```

---

Following the new Magit guidelines, this is the solution that is now working for me:

```el
(setq magit-post-display-buffer-hook
      #'(lambda ()
          (when (derived-mode-p 'magit-status-mode)
            (delete-other-windows))))
```

Comment: -1 for using advices for what can be done with existing configuration options.

Comment: Yes, as I wrote in the comment on tarsius answer, I'm working on a solution that uses existing options. This was an old fix that has been serving me well so far.

Comment: @lunaryorn edited my answer according to new Magit standards.