# magit-diff and magit-status not opening in fullframe in some contexts

Tags: magit

I would like `magit-diff` and `magit-status` to always take up the entire frame. I am trying to do this using the `fullframe` package, and have configured things according to the documentation using:

```
(fullframe magit-status magit-mode-quit-window)
(fullframe magit-diff magit-mode-quit-window)
```

This configuration works if I use `M-x magit-status/magit-diff`. But if `magit-status` gets called from certain contexts, say if I access `magit-status` from the `helm-projectile` menu (`M-g` for me), or if I access `magit-diff` from `magit-status` by hitting return on e.g., staged/unstaged changes, neither is in fullframe - and this is a problem, because this is how I usually access these modes...Any suggestions as to how to configure things so that the specified commands trigger `fullframe` regardless of how they are called? Or is it the case that different functions are actually being called when `magit-status` and `magit-diff` are called in different context? I am not sure what's going on exactly...Thank you!

Comment: Also see http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/17724/magit-status-doesnt-use-the-whole-screen-size-in-2-3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some digging through the different `magit` commands, and have found that there are indeed a number of different commands for different contexts. For now, the following seems to cover all my current use cases, but I expect I will be adding more to the list in the future:

```
(fullframe projectile-vc magit-mode-quit-window)
```

Which is called when I activate magit from `helm-projectile`, and the rest are for `magit-diff` in various context (the names should be self-explanitory, and there are more - you can use `M-x magit-diff-` and look through all the available options/completions).

```
(fullframe magit-diff-staged magit-quit-window)
(fullframe magit-diff-unstaged magit-mode-quit-window)
(fullframe magit-diff magit-mode-quit-window)
```